# Source vs Destination Port

Tags: networking, port, firewall

For example, if i want to rdp to a remote server from my local computer etc

what would be the source port and destination ports to open for network firewall?

can anyone also give more scenarios on the source and destination ports to open for network firewall? are they always the same?

Comment: You should not close local outbound ports in your firewall. The destination port is whatever RDP uses, which you can look up. Off topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On firewall you would open destination port (for RDP by default it 3389)

> Source ports are randomly generated from the unregistered port range.
>   The source/destination port works similar to your IP. The port you
>   send from, is the port the service will reply too. For instance; a
>   website is simply a server listening for connections on port 80 (or
>   443).

Comment: What are you quoting from?